# LINQ Option Missing in Data Source for Grid View

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, visual-web-developer

I don't see a LINQ option when picking a data source for a grid view - any ideas? I see the other options like SQL etc.

If I go into a page in another folder, I'm able to see this option.

I just upgraded to Visual Web Developer 2010.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a disconnect here.  I assume you are talking about the ASP.NET design view for a aspx page, and you have the Choose Data source option. The only way to get "Linq" to show up when you choose new data source in the wizard is to have a .Net 3.5 or 4.0 as your target framework.

Then this is going to walk you through selecting a context object which  if you don't have a Linq to SQL DBML setup in the project or in a referenced project you most likely will not have anything to select in the drop down.

In short it looks like you do not have the write frame work targeted by your project you are trying to do this with.

Comment: Hmm - There is an option to use LINQ to SQL when configuring a data source for a grid view - I see this when adding the gridview to a page in one folder of the project, but not another folder.

Comment: Reworked the answer based on the additional details provided in your comment.